# Spatial and temporal averaging on depth image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to do Spatial and temporal on a depth image. The spatial average can be achieved by convolution (`cv::filter2D`), for temporal average you would need to `accumulate()` `N` images, and divide by `N` but I don't know how to use OpenCV to do that.

I'm acquiring depth image from a camera.

What I tried for the spatial filter is

```
cv::Mat dst;
int kernel_size = 2;
cv::Mat kernel = cv::Mat::ones(kernel_size, kernel_size, CV_32F) / (float)(kernel_size * kernel_size);
```

Then apply filter:

```
filter2D(depth_image_ocv, dst, -1, kernel, cv::Point(-1, -1), 0, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT);
cv::imshow("Filtered Depth", dst);
cv::imshow("Depth", depth_image_ocv);
```

However, the result is horrible, see below:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How i can take the average of 100 image using opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668074/how-i-can-take-the-average-of-100-image-using-opencv)

Comment: @JHBonarius No it doesn't, I want to process a video instead of a list of images, and it doesn't take spatial filtering into consideration.

Comment: That sort of information would be useful in the question body.